# How to update the ActionBar Spinner when pressing the back button

Tags: android, spinner

I'm going mad soon, been reading Google search results for 10+ hours soon, without any luck.

I think i will drop this whole idea of using a spinner and just use tabs, but it still irritates me that i haven't found a solution. So i hope anyone could help me to understand this issue.

The project im creating has one MainActivityContainer (the main FrameLayout), and than multiple fragments (different layouts) that gets first added and than replaced inside the MainActivityContainer.

So the app only opens ONE activity and than changes pages through different fragments. This makes it super fast to change pages.

Everything except for the ActionBar Spinner works great. It doesnt get updated when pressing the back button, i.e it is still displaying the value for the last fragment.

I want to use the spinner so i easily can navigate between different fragments.

The app start page look something like this:
http://1drv.ms/1jkJpy2

The spinner items are:
1. home , 2. ImageBtn1, 3. ImageBtn2, etc.

So i can reach each destination by either clicking the image button or using the spinner. This is the functionality that i want.

But if i click imagebutton (instead of using the spinner) the value in the spinner (home) does not change to ImageBtn1. So even though i am on the page for ImageBtn1 the spinner shows "Home".

I fixed this by using actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(1); in the method for the ImageButton. So imagebuttons uses the spinners methods manually. This sets the spinner to the correct value even if pressing the imagebutton on the start page.

This all works well until i press the back button. Than i have the same problem again, the spinners value doesnt update.

So please explain to me how i can solve this. In other words: How to use a spinner actionbar with ONE activity and many fragments and still get the back button to update the spinner. I have began experimenting with the onBackPressed() method. But there has to be an easier way to achieve what i want to do???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out how to update the navigation spinner in the action bar!

In my problem, I always called actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(int); inside the onCreate() method of the activity. However, onCreate() is only called when first making a new activity. So whenever I pressed the back button, the onCreate() doesnt get called and the navigation spinner doesn't get updated. However, the onResume() function always gets called when an activity becomes visible to the user (whether the activity was just created or whether the user pressed the back button into it). So I simply called actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(int) in onResume() and the navigation spinner now updates whenever the user presses back!.

However, since you are using one activity with multiple fragments, you should probably put your actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(int) inside the onResume() of your fragments instead of the activity. And that should work!

I guess this is a good case for really learning and internalising the activity and fragment lifecycles. Back to more learning for me :).

Comment: so you deleted the "@Override public void onBackPressed()" altogether?

Comment: Just tried it, and it worked. It is a much simpler solution to what i currently have. I overcomplicated it and made a 25lines long method called UpdateSpinner(), which got called every time the back btn got pressed. Your solution is only 1 line, and will put that code in the fragment instead of the MainActivity (extends fragmentActivity) where it is now.

Comment: Yup deleted onBackPressed(). Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering if you managed to find a solution? I have a similar problem to you.

In the activity, inside the onBackPressed() method, try calling getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG); where TAG is a string that you can give when adding each of the frames (have a different TAG for each fragment).

So in code, when you are putting the fragment in:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id...., new MyFragment(), "TAG1");
```

Then the onBackPressed method would look like:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    MyFragment myFragment = (MyFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("TAG1");
if (myFragment.isVisible()) {
    getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(int);
}

}
```

Let me know if that works!

Comment: You seem to have understood exactly what i meant. Was afraid nobody understood my question. I didnt give up on the idea, and i already have a solution. It looks quiet similar to what you wrote. I will see if i can replace your solution with mine later, because mine is a bit longer... Does what you wrote work for you? I remembered this whole thing was a hazard, because i wanted the spinner also to work like the Back Btn. I.e. if a user navigated with the spinner, than if would go back to a previous state of a fragment. So the data on that fragment would still be there.

Comment: Well I'm going through a similar problem as you were going through but using activities instead of fragments (so the solution I wrote in my answer is just what I thought might work, but it isn't tested). I actually just posted it up my issue if you'd like to check it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24635889/update-actionbar-dropdown-properly

Comment: okey, will test it later and if it works i will mark it as an answer ;). I took a quick look at your question, and you seems to have the exact problem as you said. With the back btn not working correctly. I solved it, so will take a look at your question when i get the time. From a quick look: add the super.onBackPressed(); after actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(1);  ..

Answer (score 0):

**NEVER use NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST and onNavigationItemSelected it is not worth it !**

```
     @Override
     public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long itemId)

    You also cannot use menu's to do this:

   @Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
  {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

due to inflation ordering.
Reasons:

(1) it generates a "hidden" spinner, for which you can not get the id.
(2) you cannot customize this spinner
(3) you save 30 lines of code, but are permanently limited if you want to add a second bi-directional spinner 
(4) not even in the special case of "simple code" (one spinner), you lose to much.
(5) you cannot use tabs.
(6) without the id, you have no chance with fragments.

the key is actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar_custom);
and spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()...
for each spinner.
Trust me I lost hours trying each solution.
```